# Not getting values from application.properties file in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties

I am trying to configure appliaction.properties file in my spring application.

Inside my spring-servlet.xml I have

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

 <bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"
p:acquireIncrement="10" 
p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
p:maxPoolSize="100" 
p:maxStatements="0" 
p:minPoolSize="10" 
p:initialPoolSize="10" />
```

My application.properties file is inside my src folder but its not reading values from my appliaction.properties file. Do I am missing anything in configuration?

If I directly put database values then it works fine no there is no connection problem

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Have you tried adding <context:annotation-config />?

Comment: Hi Shuttsy, this is already there in my spring-servlet.xml

Comment: ok then, how are your running your xml? Buitl war running in a server? JUnit?

Comment: I am running it on my local machine on eclipse and spring-servlet.xml is configured inside <context-param> inside web.xml

Comment: I use eclipse projects and have my xml and props under src/main/resources, generally I'll run JUnits from src/test/java which simply create a Spring app context on the xml. But because running a Junit changes the classpath, I have to put a copy of the prop file under src/test/resources in order for my xml to 'see' the props.

Comment: My project is not maven and it just has project/src and webcontent folder and no test :)

Comment: Check if the props file is present under target/classes or WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: yes I have copied my props file almost everywhere in WEB-INF/classes, src/build/ and inside /src

Comment: In the generated war, the properties file needs to be at root.

Comment: yes its at root the strange thing is its reading other variable but only not reading database variables